# Syntaxes for template specialization for function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I notice there are several difference syntaxes for template specialization for function pointer types:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (Args...)> {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (*)(Args...)> {
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (&)(Args...)> {
    static constexpr int value = 3;
};

int square(int x) { return x * x; }

Foo<decltype(square)>::value == 1;  // true
Foo<decltype(&square)>::value == 2;  // true
Foo<decltype(square)&>::value == 3;  // true
```

And possibly even more...?

I know `R (*)(Args...)` is good old function pointer; I can understand `R (&)(Args...)` is a reference to a function, although it's kind of weird; but what about `R (Args...)`? My guess is its the *undecayed* type of the function. Is that correct?

**UPDATE:** It's mentioned in the comments that the form `R(Args...)` is a call signature. Now the question becomes: Why would `decltype(some_plain_function)` be matches against a call signature rather than a function pointer type? Does that mean an undecayed function type *is* a call signature?

Comment: `R(Args...)` is a [call signature](http://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects#func.def-2).

Comment: Remember how you specify template parameters to a `std::function` ? That is how it gets deduced `Res(Args)`...

Comment: @skypjack Wait...so why would `decltype(some_function)` match a call signature? Shouldn't that be a function pointer?

Comment: @ZizhengTai In your specific case it's intended as a callbale signature. More in general (I guess) `some_function` is an lvalue of a given _function type_ that decays to a function pointer when needed. That said, someone more skilled than me will come to blame me and give you a better explanation for sure. :-)

Comment: I don't like func pointers, func pointers is something more common in c than in c++ in my taste, and if you're a c++ coder, then code like a c++ coder. There are so many alternatives for function pointers (For example, design patterns will replace so many needs for function pointers) that I don't really think it needs to be in c++. It makes the code a little less readable. In c there aren't any classes, so to make something generic, you need to use c function pointers one way or another. Combining templates and function pointers make the code less readable by a long shot, and less debug-able.

Comment: The biggest alternative for function pointers in c is the polymorphism concept in OOP languages, for example.

Comment: @NoamRodrik It's like saying that the biggest alternative to eat meat is drive a car.

Comment: @skypjack Actually, *call signature* is a term specifically defined for use within that library clause ([function.objects]). The language term for that construct is *type-id* ([[dcl.name](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name)]) - `R(Args...)` is a *type-id* that names a function type, that's all.

Comment: @skypjack I wonder how you got that assumption. That sentence had no valuable information in it.

Comment: @bogdan For it is used here in almost the same way it is used for functions, I admit that I've improperly used the term *call signature*, but at least it gave the OP an idea of what I meant. Thank you as usual for the more in depth details. :-)

Comment: @skypjack No worries and no criticism from me, the rest of your explanation is spot on, I just wanted to point to the term. Just showing off, basically. :-)